# Change parameter value for all methods in a class (decorator, metaclass, other option?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, metaclass

I want to cleanup each parameter before passing it to the class methods. Right now I have smth like this:

```
from cerberus import Validator
class MyValidator(Validator):  # Validator - external lib (has it's own _validate methods)
def _validate_type_name(self, value):
    # validation code here
    # goal - to clean up value before passing to each methods (mine + from lib) e.g., value.strip() 
schema = {"name": {"type": "name"}, # name - custom type from _validate_type_name
          "planet_type": {"type": "string"}} # string - external lib type
my_dict = {"name": " Mars ", 
           "planet_type": " terrestrial "}
v = MyValidator(schema)
print(v.validate(my_dict))  # True/ False
# NOTE: I would like to do cleanup on method type level (not pass to schema)
```

I would like to clean up data before passing to the MyValidator methods (e.g., simple strip) but I don't want to make it as a separate step (just in case someone forgets to execute it before calling validation). I'd like to integrate cleanup with validation methods (external ones + mine).

I was considering either decorator on class or metaclass, but maybe there's a better approach. I don't have much experience here, asking for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make sure that the caller does the cleaning (i.e. you want them to "clean" their own copy of the value rather than having you return a modified version to them, which necessitates that it happen outside your function), then a decorator can't do much more than enforcement -- i.e. you can wrap all the functions such that a runtime exception is raised if an invalid value comes through.

The way that I'd tackle this instead of a decorator would be with types (which requires that you include `mypy` in your testing process, but you should be doing that anyway IMO).  Something like:

```
from typing import NewType

CleanString = NewType('CleanString', str)

clean(value: str) -> CleanString:
    """Does cleanup on a raw string to make it a 'clean' string"""
    value = value.strip()
    # whatever else
    return CleanString(value)


class MyValidator(Validator):
    def validate_name(self, value: CleanString) -> bool:
        # this will now flag a mypy error if someone passes a plain str to it,
        # saying a 'str' was provided where a 'CleanString' was required!
```

Static typing has the advantage of raising an error before the code is even executed, and regardless of the actual runtime value.

Comment: Samwise, that's a great idea, but I can't apply CleanString to external Validator library methods as type is not enforced there (or can I?).. Also I would much prefer to clean up value myself so method users are not troubled with the cleanup. That's why I was thinking about decorators and metaclasses. Considering this, what approach do you think will work here best?

Comment: I might need to see more of your code to understand what you're getting at -- the external validator isn't calling into your code, is it?  And if cleaning it up yourself works, why not just have a cleanup function that you call inside your validator?

Comment: Updated initial question with details

Comment: If you modify the input *internally* before you pass it to the validator, then the validator might pass even though the original input isn't actually valid -- are you sure that's what you want?  It seems like it defeats the purpose of validation.

Comment: That's an excellent point. Didn't think of that. So since I'd like to do both small cleanup and validation, my only option is to just pass values separately through the cleaner function I guess.

Comment: Yup -- that's where the typing solution I suggested comes in (it helps enforce that everything has gone through the cleaner function **before** it reaches the validator).